# Extend swing colors to custom components

Tags: java, swing, colors, custom-component, uimanager

Implementing swing applications, often you realize class of components that should have a coherent look. 
Example: `Mypanel` that extends `JPanel` and represents an applicative object and thus having a yellow background with a darker yellow border line. 
Is it possible to leverage the swing color management?
My idea is to put my colors into `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults` map and then bind them to the component somehow. 
This "somehow" is the question: how to do that in the simplest form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work if you want to customise just a few components:

```
// Specify the colors
UIDefaults uiDef = new UIDefaults();
uiDef.put("Panel.background", Color.BLUE);

// Use the colors on a specific component
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", uiDef);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(panel);
```

See the [Nimbus defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary) for key-names and default colors and painters.

Comment: works exactly as expected :-) now I'm trying to use a painter. For the border it seems that it cannot be done with a UIDefaults entry.

Comment: Caveat: The various LAFs aren't in agreement on the names of UIDefaults properties. So, "Nimbus.Overrides" will have no effect if the user is running with a different LAF.